# How to fix this problem Collect coordinates to point polygon

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, android-gps, gpsd

I have problem about my gps and plot polygon

I collect GPS every second from

```java
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

and put it to realm database

(So I things do I not good idea)
Maybe should accumulate every 10 meters

image below is result I got

[image: this is result amazing I'm lie]
my problems

1. Polygon look alike the PASTA instead of area.
2. My gps can jump over to another building(GPS is not stable)

help recommend me please.

```java
ArrayList<LatLng> coordList = new ArrayList<LatLng>(); 

      @Cleanup Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        RealmResults<PolygonAreas> PlotPolygon = realm.where(PolygonAreas.class).findAll();

                            if (PlotPolygon.size() > 0) {
                                for (PolygonAreas Polypoint : PlotPolygon) {

                                    coordList.add(new LatLng(Polypoint.getLatitude(), Polypoint.getLongitude()));

                                    try {
                                        Runnable addPolygon = new CellTowerMarkerGoogle.AddPolygon(mMap, new PolygonOptions()
                                                .addAll(coordList).fillColor(0x7F80b370).strokeColor(0x7F80b370)
                                        );
                                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(addPolygon);
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        log.debug("Exception : " + e);
                                    }
                                }
                            }


         public  static class AddPolygon implements Runnable{
                private  GoogleMap map;
                private PolygonOptions options;

                public  AddPolygon(GoogleMap map,PolygonOptions options){
                    this.map = map;
                    this.options = options;

                }
                @Override
                public void run() { map.addPolygon(options);}
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem 
Because my logic incorrect variable addPolygon 
every back again it's create new Object polygon(.addAll)
It causes the creation of overloaded objects.

How can I fix it?
I have to destroy the polygon object and recreate it every time.
The value will be updated all the time. I have to destroy and create new polygons every time to update.